# SuperscriptBox question

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I am trying to define an object type in Mathematica as follows

```
Operator /: MakeBoxes[Operator[pow_, sym_], fmt_] := 
With[{sbox = If[StringQ[sym], sym, ToBoxes[sym]]},With[{abox = SuperscriptBox[#, pow]
&@sbox},InterpretationBox[abox, Operator[pow, sym]]]]
```

This works fine when I use integer powers for example

```
X = Operator[2,x]
```

gives me $x^2$, however it doesn't work if I use a symbol for the power for example

```
Y = Operator[a+b,x]
```

should give $x^{a+b}$ but it does not. What needs to be changed?

Comment: I have no experience with interpretation boxes etc. but this looks like a quick fix: Modify second with to `...With[{abox = SuperscriptBox[#, ToBoxes[HoldForm@pow]] &@sbox},....`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! That seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess a more complex expression as exponent should be converted into a box structure as well. Why don't you just put another `ToBoxes` to convert the exponent?

```
Operator /: MakeBoxes[Operator[pow_, sym_], fmt_] := 
 With[{sbox = If[StringQ[sym], sym, ToBoxes[sym]]}, 
  With[{abox = SuperscriptBox[#, ToBoxes[pow]] &@sbox}, 
   InterpretationBox[abox, Operator[pow, sym]]]]
```

Since Kuba's comment says it doesn't work without a `HoldForm` I'll put a screenshot. Feel free to insert a hold if it doesn't work for you either

> [image]

If you want to make it more robust for situations where variables have values you could make a slight change:

```
Attributes[Operator] = {HoldFirst};
Operator /: MakeBoxes[Operator[pow_, sym_], fmt_] := 
 With[{sbox = If[StringQ[sym], sym, ToBoxes[sym]]}, 
  With[{abox = SuperscriptBox[#, ToBoxes[HoldForm[pow]]] &@sbox}, 
   InterpretationBox[abox, Operator[pow, sym]]]]
```

Now, even something like `Operator[1 + 1, x]` works, although I don't know whether this is wanted.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9 but it worked without HoldForm as well.

Comment: @Karan I can not explain what has happened. Although I have reseted kernel repeatedly this feature showed up. After pc restart, it is gone. I will delete my previous comment as misleading.